# my website isn't loading currectly. showing a 404 error when connected with a certain network,

Tags: html, wordpress, http-status-code-404, general-network-error

I recently created a website which was hosted on profreehost's free account, then I shift my website from profreehost to infinityfree and then I installed SSL on it but now website is reflecting a 404 error whenever I connect to a specific network.

otherwise the site is working completely fine from other network.

what should I do now to use it in on that network to .

Answer (score 0):

If your website is visible on other network and not on a particular network it can be due to the fact that the DNS is still not refreshed and is poiting to somewhere else. It can take somewhere around 24 hours for it to get refreshed.

You can check if that the issue by visiting https://dnschecker.org/#A and entering your website url. This should tell you if it has really changed or not.